How to plot such a histogram using gnuplot
Can anyone tell me how to plot such a figure in Gnuplot? I have three categories: A, B and C. I have three subcategories in each category: SR1, SR0.8, and SR0.5. For each SR1, SR 0.8, and SR0.5, I have two variables: SR1_L and SR1_R. I want to plot SR1_L and SR1_R in one bar, just like the figure shows. For SR1_L, fill with solid color and SR1_R with inclined line. Between the SR1, SR0.8 and SR0.5, there is no space but for the categories A, B and C, there is space there.
I appreciate for helping me to figure out how to plot such a figure. I currently have no solution for this.

This figure is generated from other software.and I  also do not know how to input the data in txt file. However, I upload the original data for some illustration.
The original data is below:
Category A:
SR1_L: 0.5    SR1_R:0.5
SR0.8_L: 0.6  SR0.8_R:0.4
SR0.5_L: 0.7   SR0.5_R:0.3

Category B:
SR1_L: 0.5    SR1_R:0.5
SR0.8_L: 0.6  SR0.8_R:0.4
SR0.5_L: 0.7   SR0.5_R:0.3

Category C:
SR1_L: 0.5    SR1_R:0.5
SR0.8_L: 0.6  SR0.8_R:0.4


Please edit your question to include sample data that should generate this view. Make it so readers can copy/paste into their environment. Use the {} tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to achieve correct code/data/output/errMsg formatting. Good luck.

Hello, Shellter, i don't know how to generate this figure in gnuplot. So I plot it in another software.  I even do not know how to input the data in a txt file and whether there are some requirements.  I upload the txt file and contain the origin data.

@Edward you show the original data, but are you flexible in the data format to minimize the complexity with the plot command? And is it always true that SRx_L + SRx_R = 1? Why is SR0.5_ is missing the last group?

Hi, Theozh, the relationship SRx_L+SRx_R=1 always exists and the last group did not have SR0.5_. I have edited the original data again

This question reminds me to this one: How to create a rowstacked and clustered bar chart in gnuplot?, but somehow a bit different.
Maybe there is a way with some gnuplot-intrinsic plotting style requiring some special input data format, but I would start from a flat list.
Here is a suggestion which should be general enough to work also with different numbers of categories, subcategories and subsubcategories, (e.g. "L", "R", "M", "K", ...).
Some comments:

automatically create lists of unique items for the categories by (mis)using stats command. The order is in the order of first occurrence. (check help stats)

it's easier to sum-up if your data is in an array. Again (mis)using the stats command to get the data from the file into the array. (check help arrays)

using the plotting style with boxxyerror offers the highest flexibility (check help boxxyerror)

keyentry is used to create the legend (check help keyentry)

on purpose, I changed your original data, to see that there is a difference between the categories.


Data: SO78325960.dat
A   SR1     L   0.5
A   SR1     R   0.5
A   SR0.8   L   0.6
A   SR0.8   R   0.4
A   SR0.5   L   0.7
A   SR0.5   R   0.3
B   SR1     L   0.52
B   SR1     R   0.52
B   SR0.8   L   0.64
B   SR0.8   R   0.44
B   SR0.5   L   0.78
B   SR0.5   R   0.38
C   SR1     L   0.5
C   SR1     R   0.5
C   SR0.8   L   0.4
C   SR0.8   R   0.4

Script:
### plot special barchart
reset session

FILE = "SO78325960.dat"
c0 = 1   # columns for L0,L1,L2
c1 = 2
c2 = 3
c3 = 4   # column for y-data

L0 = L1 = L2 = ''
addToList(list,col) = (_s=sprintf(' "%s"',strcol(col)), strstrt(list,_s) ? '' : _s)
stats FILE u (L0=L0.addToList(L0,c0), L1=L1.addToList(L1,c1), L2=L2.addToList(L2,c2)) nooutput
N0         = words(L0)
N1         = words(L1)
N2         = words(L2)
Ngap       = 1
myBoxwidth = 0.8

PosX0(n0)        = n0*(N1+Ngap) + (N1-1)/2.
PosX1(n0,n1)     = n0*(N1+Ngap) + n1
myPattern(n)     = word("3 6 2 7", n)
Filter(n0,n1,n2) = strcol(c0) eq word(L0,n0+1) && strcol(c1) eq word(L1,n1+1) && strcol(c2) eq word(L2,n2)

array A[N0*N1*N2]
set table $Dummy
    plot for [n0=0:N0-1] for [n1=0:N1-1] for [n2=1:N2] FILE \
        u ($0==0 ? (i=n0*N1*N2+n1*N2+n2, A[i]=0) : 0, Filter(n0,n1,n2) ? A[i]=column(c3) : 0) w table
unset table
undef $Dummy

set offsets 0.5,0.5, graph 0.05,0
set yrange[0:]
set xtics out
set style fill solid 0.3
set key out noautotitle noenhanced
set for [i=0:N0-1] xtic (word(L0,i+1) PosX0(i))
set xrange[-0.5:]

plot for [n0=0:N0-1] for [n1=0:N1-1] for [n2=1:N2] '+' every ::::0 \
         u (PosX1(n0,n1)):(y0=A[n0*N1*N2+n1*N2+n2]/2., y0 + sum[i=1:n2-1] A[n0*N1*N2+n1*N2+i]): \
         (myBoxwidth/2.):(y0) w boxxy lc n1+1 fill pattern myPattern(n2), \
     for [n1=1:N1] for [n2=1:N2] keyentry w boxes lc n1 fill pattern myPattern(n2) ti sprintf("%s_%s",word(L1,n1), word(L2,n2))
### end of script

Result:


Thanks, theozh. This script is helpful. By the way, is there a way to reduce the spacing between the subcategory of A to zero?

@Edward yes, of course. Simply change the line to myBoxwidth=1.0. Problem solved? Question answered?

Yes, Thanks, theozh. Really help a lot

@Edward glad to hear. If it was helpful please upvote and if it answered your question, please accept the answer indicating that the question is answered and your problem is solved.

This is an answer using 'columnstacked histogram'.
First, we need to consider data layout. Because gnuplot reads and processes data files line by line, it is very difficult for gnuplot to handle directly your data format. For this answer, I prepared the following data format.
# A
SR1 SR0.8 SR0.5
0.5 0.6 0.7
0.5 0.4 0.3


# B
SR1 SR0.8 SR0.5
0.5 0.6 0.7
0.5 0.4 0.3


# C
SR1 SR0.8 SR0.5
0.5 0.6 ?
0.5 0.4 ?

The data is divided into three blocks with double blank lines, and you can select the category A data by specifying index 'A' in the plot command. Let's proceed with the strategy of drawing this data with 'columnstacked histograms'.
In your figure, the L data are filled with solid color, but the R data are filled with hatch. Since it was difficult to mix solid color and hatched pattern, I decided to fill all the boxes with solid colors. I will change the color series as follows.
set linetype 1 lc rgb "#ff0000" 
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#ff8080"
set linetype 3 lc rgb "#00ff00" 
set linetype 4 lc rgb "#80ff80"
set linetype 5 lc rgb "#0000ff" 
set linetype 6 lc rgb "#8080ff"
set linetype cycle 6

The following function is provided as a way to select the appropriate color for each box.
array category2 = ["SR1", "SR0.8", "SR0.5"].
CN(c,n) = 2*index(category2,c) - 1 + n

This function works as follows
print CN("SN1",0)   #=> 1
print CN("SN1",1)   #=> 2
print CN("SN0.8",0) #=> 3
print CN("SN0.8",1) #=> 4
print CN("SN0.5",0) #=> 5
print CN("SN0.5",1) #=> 6

Finally, here is the script created by combining the above elements.
#
# Rearranged data
#
$data << EOD
# A
SR1 SR0.8 SR0.5
0.5 0.6 0.7
0.5 0.4 0.3


# B
SR1 SR0.8 SR0.5
0.5 0.6 0.7
0.5 0.4 0.3


# C
SR1 SR0.8 SR0.5
0.5 0.6 ?
0.5 0.4 ?
EOD

#
# Redefinition of linetype sequence
#
set linetype 1 lc rgb "#ff0000" 
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#ff8080"
set linetype 3 lc rgb "#00ff00" 
set linetype 4 lc rgb "#80ff80"
set linetype 5 lc rgb "#0000ff" 
set linetype 6 lc rgb "#8080ff"
set linetype cycle 6

#
# Axis settings
#
set tmargin screen 0.9
set bmargin screen 0.2
set border 3
set xtics offset 0,0.5 scale 1 out nomirror 
set yrange [0:1.2] 
set ytics 0,0.1,1 out nomirror
set key out noenhanced

#
# Histogram settings
#
set style data histograms
set style histogram columnstacked
set style fill solid 0.7 border lc "black"
set boxwidth 0.8

#
# Datafile settings
#
set datafile columnheader

#
# Support function
#
array category2 = ["SR1", "SR0.8", "SR0.5"]
CN(c,n) = 2*index(category2,c) - 1 + n

#
# Plot command
#
plot newhistogram "A", \
     c="SR1"   $data i "A" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     c="SR0.8" $data i "A" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     c="SR0.5" $data i "A" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     newhistogram "B", \
     c="SR1"   $data i "B" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     c="SR0.8" $data i "B" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     c="SR0.5" $data i "B" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     newhistogram "C", \
     c="SR1"   $data i "C" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     c="SR0.8" $data i "C" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     c="SR0.5" $data i "C" u c:(CN(c,$0)) lc var t columnhead, \
     c="SR1"   keyentry w boxes fs s 0.5 lc CN(c,0) t c."_L", \
     c="SR1"   keyentry w boxes fs s 0.5 lc CN(c,1) t c."_R", \
     c="SR0.8" keyentry w boxes fs s 0.5 lc CN(c,0) t c."_L", \
     c="SR0.8" keyentry w boxes fs s 0.5 lc CN(c,1) t c."_R", \
     c="SR0.5" keyentry w boxes fs s 0.5 lc CN(c,0) t c."_L", \
     c="SR0.5" keyentry w boxes fs s 0.5 lc CN(c,1) t c."_R"

The plot command is quite verbose, but it can generate the following figure.

